# How to get request URI without Path Variables?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

The Method `request.getRequestURI()` returns URI with path variables.
The following example service takes Path Variable. How can I get URL that without Path Variables

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUser/{username}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUser(@PathVariable String username)
```

if i make request like this(

localhost:8080/user/getUser/tommy

)
`request.getRequestURI()` returns with path variable.

```
user/getUser/tommy
```

I want to get a result like this:
`user/getUser/`
or
`user/getUser`

How can I get the path without path variables?

Comment: Why/where do you need it?

Comment: Not a solution using a direct method call, but you could do something like getRequestURI().replace(username, ""). I admit not the most clean work-around...

Comment: I do Service based access control by keeping context path and service url in database.  When I get the first request with filters, I intervene and make inquiries. @SotiriosDelimanolis

Comment: getRequestURI() simply doesn't come with service path, so I can't use replace @KDW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using @RequestParam instead of @PathVariable for get services in my Controller classes

Example

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/getUser", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<UserDTO> getUser(@RequestParam String username)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any Spring MVC way. You can parse from one of the available `HttpServletRequest` methods.

For instance

```java
@Controller
public class SampleController {

    @GetMapping("/sample/path/{last}")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> sampleMethod(@PathVariable String last, HttpServletRequest request) {

        System.out.println(request.getContextPath());
        System.out.println(request.getRequestURI());

        String path = request.getServletPath();
        System.out.println(path);
        System.out.println(path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf(last)));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(last);
    }
}
```

```
/context
/context/sample/path/boom
/sample/path/boom
/sample/path/
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have to write in Filter class.  It comes with the parameter set in filter class, so I can't parse it.

Comment: You might need to provide some more context in the question. Maybe show your filter code and where you want to get the value? Filter will have the `HttpServletRequest` and could parse from like the last path separator, for instance.

Answer (score -1):

Not possible. You have to write logic by your self to extract the path variable.